# Matching Multiple 'id' Values Using RegEx in Combination with HTML::TreeBuilder

Tags: python, regex, dictionary, tree, html-tree

I've got a list of URLs in an array:

```
http://www.site.sx/doc1.html
http://www.site.sx/doc2.html
http://www.site.sx/doc3.html
.
.
.
```

Let's view the contents of the first page, namely doc1.html:

```
<?xmlversion = "1.0" encoding = "utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN"
     "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
   <head>
      <title>Birds</title>
   </head>

   <body>
      <p>Some bird's feather's aren't actually blue, they're clear.</p>
      <!--LOOK HERE--><p id = "abc123FACT1xyz789">There exists an insect that makes 100-decibel sounds.</p> 
   </body>
</html>
```

Now, let's view the contents of the second page, namely doc2.html:

```
<?xmlversion = "1.0" encoding = "utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN"
     "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
   <head>
      <title>Cats</title>
   </head>

   <body>
      <p>Moota goes from house to house.</p>
      <!--LOOK HERE--><p id = "abc123FACT2xyz789">Falling from a higher altitude might be better than a lower one.</p> 
   </body>
</html>
```

doc3.html will have the same `abc123.....xyz789`-type of pattern for its `ìd` value, and so will the rest of the pages in my array. I want to capture the text content of each one. There is only one `id` value in each document with this particular pattern. Of course, there are multiple `id` values all over the document in reality, but--for sake of simplicity--we can disregard this.

---

BIG PICTURE: I want to put each match in like this:

```
$tree->look_down( _tag => 'p' , id => "abc123.*xyz789")->as_text; # NOT SURE HOW TO MAKE AN ARRAY OF MATCHES...
```

Comment: You know, `dictionary = dict(zip(TITLES, URLS))`, or something.

Comment: you've said what you'd like, but what is the question?

Comment: give us more ids. We can not find a pattern if you give us one example  of a string without telling us what the id is.

Comment: @mrhobo, what? Really? I must be terrible at explaining things... OK, try this, see my edit--in progress.

Answer (score 0):

```
my $match = $tree->look_down( _tag => 'p' , id => qr{abc123.*xyz789} )->as_text;
```

This will get what I'm after.